# How to remove the value from the first "to" and till the first comma (,) for a string in java

Tags: java

I have a string:

```
Expected attribute value 'internalClosureRule' but was 'internalClosureRule2' - comparing <Option name="internalClosureRule"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name to <Option name="internalClosureRule2"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,
Expected attribute value 'opt_cpd_p2s_skip' but was 'opt_cpd_p2s_skip2' - comparing <Option name="internalClosureRule"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name to <Option name="internalClosureRule2"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name
```

I would like to remove the Value from the first "to" and till the first comma (,) and like that the same pattern should go on for the "," separated values in the string i.e. 
i want to print my string in separate line which are without the "to" and till its "," comma which is at the end.

My Expected Output is:

```
Expected attribute value 'internalClosureRule' but was 'internalClosureRule2' - comparing <Option name="internalClosureRule"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,
Expected attribute value 'opt_cpd_p2s_skip' but was 'opt_cpd_p2s_skip2' - comparing <Option name="internalClosureRule"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,
```

Could someone please provide some help?

Comment: show us the string

Comment: String StringDiff = differences.toString();
StringDiff Value is the one which i written above in the beginning i.e. [I have a String]

Comment: Show us your input and output you want

Comment: Hi Srinivasan , In the beginning of my question i have my string input a comma separated value from that im trying to use substring or split so that i can remove the contents starting from the first "to" till the first comma ","  and then it continues

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is by using `String#replaceAll` method with a regular expression and replace it with empty string (`""`). In your case the pattern is easy and it is

`to.*,`

where:

`to` -> for "to" word.

`.*` -> for any character

`,` -> for comma

```
    @Test
    public void fromFirstToTillComma()
    {
        String string = "Expected attribute value 'internalClosureRule' but was 'internalClosureRule2' - comparing <Option name=\"internalClosureRule\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name to <Option name=\"internalClosureRule2\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,";
        String expected = "Expected attribute value 'internalClosureRule' but was 'internalClosureRule2' - comparing <Option name=\"internalClosureRule\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,";
        string = string.replaceAll("to.*,", "").trim();
        string += ",";
        assertEquals(expected, string);
    }
```

More about `Pattern`s can be found [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

---

***After comment:***
Instead of treat all the values at the same time, split the problem into smaller ones, by splitting the values by comma. Then you will have each value separated and you can use my regular expression. Finally sum the values again separated with comma.

Code:

```
@Test
public void fromFirstToTillComma() {
    String string = "Expected attribute value 'internalClosureRule' but was 'internalClosureRule2' - comparing <Option name=\"internalClosureRule\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name to <Option name=\"internalClosureRule2\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,"
            + "Expected attribute value 'opt_cpd_p2s_skip' but was 'opt_cpd_p2s_skip2' - comparing <Option name=\"internalClosureRule\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name to <Option name=\"internalClosureRule2\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,";
    String expected = "Expected attribute value 'internalClosureRule' but was 'internalClosureRule2' - comparing <Option name=\"internalClosureRule\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,"
            + "Expected attribute value 'opt_cpd_p2s_skip' but was 'opt_cpd_p2s_skip2' - comparing <Option name=\"internalClosureRule\"...> at /TCXML[1]/Header[1]/TransferFormula[1]/OptionSet[1]/Option[1]/@name,";

    String lines[] = string.split(",");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line : lines) {
        line += ","; //Add the comma at the end because string.split(",") removed it
        line = line.replaceAll("to.*,", "").trim();
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(","); //Each value separated with comma
    }
    String clear = sb.toString().trim();
    assertEquals(expected, clear);
}
```

Comment: thanks george for the idea, but this one replaces only my first string value, but i have many comma separated values in this way i want it to be done for all.

Comment: @manideepguptaDevadula If i understand correctly, why don't you split your comma separated values by (System.lineSeparator())? You will have each of them as one, and then apply my way.

Comment: Thanks George this really worked, i tried all options but the "replaceall" one worked really well